# Processing multiple values sent to Flask request.args.get

Tags: python

I would like to submit and process multiple form values separated by spaces to a Flask route.  But I don't have a full understanding request.args.get() works.  Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/rsr')
def rsr():
  outval = request.args.get('value',0, type=str)
  outvalsplit = outval.split()
  for val in outvalsplit:
  ......
```

I am expecting split() to separate each value and then iterate through each one.  It seems as if the string is processed as one long string rather than separate values.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code iterates over the original query argument string character by character:

```
for val in outval:
```

To iterate over the list of `split()` items:

```
for val in outvalsplit:
```

Comment: That was actually a typo in my question.  What you've commented is what's actually in my code.  I'll try to edit my question now.

Answer (score 0):

So you're sending a GET-request to `http://yourserver.tld/rsr?value=foo` or `http://yourserver.tld/rsr?value=more than one value`?

Then the string `more than one value` gets probably URL-encoded to `more%20than%20one%20value`. It's just an assumption. Could you check that? If that's the case then you should probably URL-decode the value prior to splitting or split at each `%20`.